# Box2D Testbed example results in segfault

Tags: linux, debian, box2d

on Linux Debian 8.8 Jessie (x86-64) I compiled sources of Box2D.
Sources "Box2D_v2.3.07z" and compiling instructions taken here:
[iforce2d](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-linux)

Helloworld example succesfully runs, but Testbed example gives a segmentation fault.
GDB reports a CRC mismatch:

```
warning: the debug information found in "/lib64/ld-2.19.so" does not match "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" (CRC mismatch).
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

LDD reports:

```
 ldd Testbed 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea67e6000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007fa02668f000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fa026343000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fa02613a000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fa025f1d000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa025bda000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa0259c7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa0256bc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa0253bb000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa0251a4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa024df9000)
    libnvidia-tls.so.340.102 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.102 (0x00007fa024bf6000)
    libnvidia-glcore.so.340.102 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.102 (0x00007fa021fe1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa021ddd000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa021bd8000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa0219b5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055da082c4000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa0217b1000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa0215ab000)
```

GDB Backtrace reports:

```
bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff32c1291 in init () at dlerror.c:177
#2  0x00007ffff32c1687 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7ffff32c1130 <dlsym_doit>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd770) at dlerror.c:129
#3  0x00007ffff32c1198 in __dlsym (handle=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>) at dlsym.c:70
#4  0x00007ffff78cd69e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff78b1556 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff7dea97d in call_init (l=0x7ffff7ff7a90, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffd8b8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffd8c8)
    at dl-init.c:64
#7  0x00007ffff7deaaa3 in call_init (env=0x7fffffffd8c8, argv=0x7fffffffd8b8, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:36
#8  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1a8, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8b8, env=0x7fffffffd8c8) at dl-init.c:126
#9  0x00007ffff7ddd1ca in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#10 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffffffdbe6 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you have a Debian OS setup/install issue with your libraries. That said, it may be there's a Box2D problem that's also exercising this OS issue but I don't see anything that looks to me like sign of Box2D having a problem other than a dependent library not working for it.

Comment: I believe the warning and the segfault are two different issues. What does `bt full` report for the program? Do you get a trace, or is the stack hosed? (You should also ensure the system is up-to-date with `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`).